# Send email from Google Sheets when a row has been filled out with 'Complete' in a column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I am attempting to create an email notification system that will send out an email notification once a row is marked with Complete in one of the columns. I am needing to pull information from the completed row to send in the email message.

Right now I have it working with a hard coded specific row, but I am stuck on figuring out how to make the script look at and only grab the data from the row that was just marked as complete. I have seen some things with for loops to have it parse through an array of the data from the spreadsheet but I am not sure how I would implement that in this use case.

```
function sendEmail() {


// Setting variables for email message and sheets to use
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(2,5).getValue();
var subject = sheet2.getRange(1,1).getValue();
var whatrequested = sheet1.getRange(2,3).getValue();
var quality = sheet2.getRange(2,6).getValue();
var notes = sheet1.getRange(2,7).getValue();
var status = sheet1.getRange(2,8).getValue();
var message = sheet2.getRange(1,2).getValue();
  
//Inserting variables with row data into subject and message  
message=message.replace("<whatrequested>",whatrequested).replace("<status>",status).replace("<quality>",quality).replace("<notes>",notes);
subject=subject.replace("<whatrequested>",whatrequested).replace("<status>",status);

//Sending the email
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

}
```

Comment: I can see you are retrieving data from two different sheets. Where (sheet and column) is the `Complete` value you want to look for? I assume you want to send multiple row data as emails (all those that contain `Complete`), or just one? And what about the second sheet? What data should be retrieved from there? Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on (free of sensitive information), clearly indicating the desired purpose?

Answer (score 0):

put the column into an array, loop through the array, send if complete, add last sent date.
The trick is 'just completed'. Sheets can process slowly so you don't want to trust it to not send twice.

*** not tested but should be a good head start.

```
function ifComplete() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2'); // assuming this is where the complete tag will be.
var col = 5 // F=5 or whatever column the 'complete' tag will be in
var colto = sheet2.getDataRange().getLastRow();
/*
you can see where doing dumping into an array then we'll drop it all back in the original data
this is way faster than .getRange() for each element.
*/
var compRange = sheet2.getRange(1,col,colto,2); // row,col,rows,columns
var completes = compRange.getValues(); 
/*
completes has all your values in the format [[][]] with each row 
including complete or not and the row beside it being a timestamp for when sent.
*/
var sentdate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy/MM/dd"));

for (r==0;r<completes.length;r++) {

if(completes[r[0]=='Complete' && completes[r][1]=='') {
sendEmail();
r[1]=sentdate; // assumes you won't find 'Complete' in any headers or pre-header rows
}// if
}// for r

compRange.setValues(completes); // pastes original values back in with updates
//to resend, just delete the sent date
}// function ifComplete
```

Comment: This seems to work with a couple of adjustments for parsing through the Complete column, but what would be the best way to also parse through the other columns? The problem is that I need to send an email with data that is only from 1 row once marked complete and then move onto the next row and continue doing the same thing. I am unfortunately pretty new to coding in JavaScript so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Ah yes... I don't have enough room to answer that question in this comment.

Comment: I can't even add an f'n line break. Anyway... the trick is to grab all the data and put it into arrays (sheet1 and sheet2). then bounce around those arrays to create your emails.
So sendEmail() would get parameters from ifComplete. Those parameters would be pulled from the row you're on. Sorry... it's a whole thing. Your message has like 7 variables 2 sheets. I don't know anything about them, so I'm not sure how that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help above. It steered me in the right direction with a little bit of additional tinkering I was able to get the end result that I was looking for. Posting here in case anyone else wants to use this same functionality.

```
    function sendEmail() {


// Setting variables for message and sheets

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1')
  var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();

//for loop to go through the spreadsheet
  for (var i = 2;i<=lr;i++) {
  
    var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(i,5).getValue();
    var whatrequested = sheet1.getRange(i,3).getValue();
    var quality = sheet1.getRange(i,6).getValue();
    var notes = sheet1.getRange(i,7).getValue();
    var status = sheet1.getRange(i,8).getValue();
    var message = sheet2.getRange(1,2).getValue();
    var subject = sheet2.getRange(1,1).getValue();
    var quotaLeft = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()
    var emailSent = sheet1.getRange(i,9).getValue();
    Logger.log(quotaLeft)

    
//Inserting variables into email subject and message  
  message=message.replace("<whatrequested>",whatrequested).replace("<status>",status).replace("<quality>",quality).replace("<notes>",notes);
  subject=subject.replace("<whatrequested>",whatrequested).replace("<status>",status);


    
//Sending the email
    if ((emailSent !== "EMAIL_SENT") && (status.match("Complete") !=null)) {
    //if (status.match("Complete") !=null) {
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet1.getRange(i,9).setValue('EMAIL_SENT');
      Logger.log(emailAddress)
      Logger.log(subject)
      Logger.log(message)
    }
  }
};
```